# Kotlin app with a lot of coroutines is locking up

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I'm working on a backend application that has a unique use case. For each "entity," I have to poll 4 APIs every 5 seconds. I also have data flowing from other sources (message queues, an internal API that I need to poll), so I decided that Kotlin's coroutines with the actor design pattern was decent approach.

I have 5 high level coroutines, about 6 Kotlin coroutine "actors", and each "entity" is a coroutine that spawns child coroutines to perform the polling.

So essentially it looks like this.

- a Master coroutine spawns 5 high level coroutines that helps manage the state of the app.
- the master coroutine then spawns a coroutine for each "entity" that is in the database.
- the entity coroutine spawns 4 children coroutines that is performing the every 5 second polling.

Polling coroutines basically look like this:

```
while (isActive) {
  try {
    pollApi()
  } catch (e: Exception) {
      log.error(e)
  } finally {
      if (isActive) delay(5 seconds)
  }
}
```

I performed my local testing with ~5 entities and everything works great. I then deployed to AWS and slowly added more entities (10 at a time), and I noticed that all coroutines seem to be locked up/suspended once I reached about 60 entities. I also noticed the exact same behavior when I launch the app with an immediate 25 entities.

Since there is a lot of API calls and delays going on here, I am using Dispatchers.IO for all of my coroutine scopes.

Any idea what might be going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: How long do your API calls usually take? Is it theoretically possible to make this many calls with this period? Spawning a lot of coroutines is most likely not the problem. Note that using `Disptachers.IO` doesn't magically solve the problem of blocking calls, though. It merely spawns threads as needed for IO, so if you make many concurrent blocking calls, you may end up with many threads (max 64) instead of just many coroutines. I guess a lot will also depend on the HTTP client you're using and how it manages its own thread pool as well.